# When to use $ vs #?

Tags: mybatis, ibatis

I am confused about using `$ vs #`. I didn't found any guides for this. I used them as
`name = #{name}`, `name like '%${word}%'`, `order by name ${orderAs}`,`where name = #{word}`
Sometimes , these are work fine but at the sometimes , parameters aren't included or gave me error like

> org.apache.ibatis.reflection.ReflectionException: There is no getter
>   for property named 'name'.......

So, I'd like to know when to use `$` or `#` ?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Following the `myBatis` guidelines `#{}` is used in your sql statements.

If you take a look any of MyBatis Reference in the Section [Mapper XML Files](http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/sqlmap-xml.html#select) it says explicity:

> Notice the parameter notation:
>
> `#{id}`

Otherwise `${}` is for

1- Configuration [properties](http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/configuration.html#properties).

For example:

```
<properties resource="org/mybatis/example/config.properties">
  <property name="username" value="dev_user"/>
  <property name="password" value="F2Fa3!33TYyg"/>
</properties>
```

Then the properties can be used like next:

```
<dataSource type="POOLED">
  <property name="username" value="${username}"/>
  <property name="password" value="${password}"/>
</dataSource>
```

2- String Substitution  `${}` ([Parameters section](http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/sqlmap-xml.html#Parameters)):

> By default, using the #{} syntax will cause MyBatis to generate
>   PreparedStatement properties and set the values safely against the
>   PreparedStatement parameters (e.g. ?). While this is safer, faster and
>   almost always preferred, sometimes you just want to directly inject a
>   string unmodified into the SQL Statement. For example, for ORDER BY,
>   you might use something like this:
>
> ORDER BY ${columnName}
>
> Here MyBatis won't modify or escape the string.
>
> NOTE It's not safe to accept input from a user and supply it to a
>   statement unmodified in this way. This leads to potential SQL
>   Injection attacks and therefore you should either disallow user input
>   in these fields, or always perform your own escapes and checks.

So definitively in `name like '%${word}%' or`order by name ${orderAs}` you need to use String substitution not a prepared statement.

Comment: `name = ${name}` , `name like '%#{word}%'` these are not ok. *#{} is used in your sql statements....* I did not understand.I am using mybatis exp within sql statements. Isn't ? *${} is just for Java properties..* Do you mean these may be varried depends on parameter type ?

Comment: can u support me a link to follow guidelines as you described ?

Comment: Thank your for your edited answer.But I'm not satisfied yet. Can you explain me about why `order by name #{orderAs}` and `name like '%#{word}%'` give me error ?

Comment: I've edited again the question. You were right, there are some cases where isn't a PreparedStatemnt, just a String substitution and in this cases is need to do it with `${}`.  One example is the `order by`

Comment: perfect .. Thanks

Comment: Per the point "2- String Substitution  ${}" in this Answer: An operative part of the description there for me is, "Here MyBatis won't modify or escape the string".  So in cases where #{} doesn't work, I infer it must be because of that "modification" or "escaping", where ${} doesn't do that.  I'm not sure what are examples of "modifications", but I think one may be that Strings referenced with #{} might have quote chars added around them (because the # in this works: "... name IN <foreach item="item" index="index" collection="collection" open="(" separator="," close=")">#{item}</foreach> ...")

Comment: I want to use $ variable in table name but first make it lower case. I tried `my_table_name_LOWER(${country})` and it doesn't work because the table name is formed as `my_table_name_LOWER(IN)`. How do I make it work?

Answer (score 14):

This (**${}** - simple variable)

```
SELECT * from user where usernum = ${usernum}
```

translates into this

```
SELECT * from user where usernum = 666
```

, but this (**#{}** - equivalent to PreparedStatement in JDBC)

```
SELECT * from user where usernum = #{usernum}
```

translates into

```
SELECT * from user where usernum = ?
```

, so the best usage would be something like

```
SELECT * from ${tablename} where name = #{name}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was also confused with this . Then I did some research. I had a query which is something like `select * from tablename h where h.id=#userid#` in ibatis. Then I had to migrate it into mybatis 3 . The same statement didnt work. So I had changed it into `select * from tablename h where h.id=#{userid}`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30321442)